# Selenium: Unable to run code

Tags: selenium, xpath

Hey I'm trying to convert the information below into two steps to be run in selenium.

For some reason even the xpath won't run in selenium, can someone please help.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

xpath is case sensitive. Try `//a[@href="http://google.com"]`